# Unable to cast object of type C# .Net Core

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-core, .net-core

I'm getting error Unable to cast object of type 'Enterprise.SynCore.Tag to type 'Enterprise.SynCore.DbRow' and I'm unsure of what the issue would be.

Am I missing something in the service or controller somewhere?

**DBRow.Slv.cs**

```
   public override bool Equals(object x)
        {
            return Tag == ((DbRow)x).Tag;
        }
```

**ActionService.cs**

```
namespace SynApi.Services
{

 public interface IActionService
{
    DbrAction[] GetActions(string userId, string sessionId);
}

public class ActionService : IActionService
{
    private DataContext _context;

    public ActionService(DataContext context)
    {
        _context = context;
    }

    DbrAction[] IActionService.GetActions(string userId, string sessionId)
    {
        UserStateHelper ush = new UserStateHelper();
        UserState us = ush.CreateUserState(sessionId);
        XioTable xt = new XioTable(us, T.User);
        DbrUser user = (DbrUser)xt.LoadSingleRow(us.UserTag, C.User_DefaultActionTag);

        DbrAction[] actions = { };
        List<DbrAction> dbrActions = new List<DbrAction>();
        xt = new XioTable(us, T.Action);
        xt.SelectCols(C.Action_Description, C.Action_ActionName, C.Action_FolderTag, C.Action_ActionType, C.Action_PrimaryTable);
        xt.LoadData();
        foreach (DbrAction action in xt.GetAllRows(C.Action_FolderTag))
        {
            if (!DbrAction.IsTableDeprecated(action.PrimaryTable))
            {
                if (action.ActionType == ActionType.View || action.ActionType == ActionType.Dashboard)
                    dbrActions.Add(action);
            }
        }
        us.Completed(LogEntryType.GetStartupProfileData, null);
        return dbrActions.ToArray();
    }
}
}
```

**ActionsController.cs**

```
    public class ActionsController : ControllerBase
{
    private IActionService _actionService;
    public ActionsController(IActionService actionService)
    {
        _actionService = actionService;
    }

    //GET: api/Actions
    [HttpGet]
    public IActionResult GetActions(string userId, string sessionId)
    {
        DbrAction[] dbrActions = _actionService.GetActions(userId, sessionId);
        return Ok(dbrActions);
    }
```

Comment: If this error happens in that `Tag == ((DbRow)x).Tag`, then that `x` is of type `Tag`, not `DbRow`. But from your posted code it is not clear why this is called. Check (using `is` or `as` operators) whether that `x` *really* is a DbRow (return false if it isn't)

Comment: Indeed, `Equals(object)` should *not* throw an exception if it's presented with a reference to an object of a different type - it should just return false.

Comment: The code you've shown in DBRow.Slv.cs is wrong. It's casting unconditionally, which will throw an exception if we pass anything but a DBRow into it. Separately you'd need to work out why something is calling Equals and passing a non-DBRow in - looking at the stack trace for the exception would help you there.